# Value of property IamInstanceProfile must be of type String

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-cloudformation

I want to reference my instance profile value from another stack.

If the Instance profile resource would be in the template, I could !Ref Name of the resource

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'

Parameters:
  SSMInstanceProfileStack:
    Description: instance profile stack
    Type: String
    Default: instance-profile

Resources:
  Ec2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      ImageId: ami-077a5b1762a2dde35
      IamInstanceProfile: 
        - Fn::ImportValue:
            Fn::Sub: "${SSMInstanceProfileStack}-Suffix" 
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: Ec2SandPit
Outputs:
  Ec2Output:
    Description: A bare bone Ec2 instance 
    Value: !Ref Ec2
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-Ec2"
```

I am getting this error, the resource is deployed.

```
Value of property IamInstanceProfile must be of type String
```

Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IamInstanceProfile` should be a **string only**, not a list of strings. So it should be (remove `-`):

```
      IamInstanceProfile: 
        Fn::ImportValue:
          Fn::Sub: "${SSMInstanceProfileStack}-Suffix"
```

Comment: thanks. makes sense. defo to late for me to think straight!

Answer (score 0):

for ec2 instance it will expect profilenName only.
for launch configuration and launchtemplate we can give ARN as well.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).